# How to prove these two equations in measure theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am a self learner in measure theory. I meet a problem as below.  Can any one give some hint for it. I will solve it in details. Many thanks !

Let ${X_n}$ be i.i.d random variables. Then

1. $$n^{-1} \max_{1\leq k \leq n } |X_k|\rightarrow 0 \text{ in probability}\iff nP(|X_1|>n)=o(1)$$
2. $$n^{-1} \max_{1\leq k \leq n } |X_k|\rightarrow 0\text{ almost surely} \iff E|X_1|<\infty$$

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. That will give us an idea of how far you have progressed and what tools you have available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for 1 :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(\max_{1\leq k\leq n} |X_k| \leq a) &= \mathbb P(|X_1|\leq a,\dots,|X_n|\leq a)\\
&= \mathbb P(|X_1|\leq a)^n
\end{align*}

Hint for 2 :
Borel–Cantelli lemma

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though I still can not make sure.  For hint one, there is $1/n$?  For hint two, Borel Lemma is for if part, though not only if part.